# "Wrap with try...catch" in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

Can I select a block of code and have IntelliJ wrap it with a "try...catch" ?

Is there a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Intellij idea default keymap/keyboard shortcut for Windows and Mac: https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

Answer (score 330, accepted):

Select the code, and then either:

- Choose `Code` > `Surround With`
- Press Ctrl-Alt-T. (Command-Option-T for OS X.)

From time to time, I like to check the [*Productivity Guide*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/using-productivity-guide.html) via the *Help > My Productivity* menu item.  Not only does it tell me all the shortcuts, but it keeps track of how many times I've used each one and when I last used it.  I can see how well I'm leveraging the shortcuts.

Comment: Nice one about the productivity guide, never saw it before ;)

Comment: I'm glad you like it, too.  Those JetBrains folks are a cut above.  Every new version is better than the one before.  I just got 11 - it's amazing how fast everything is, now that I'm running on SSDs.    "Develop with pleasure", indeed.

Comment: In Linux it's  Ctrl+Alt+WinKey+T

Comment: `Productivity Guide` is really useful that I did know before. Thanks a lot.

FWIW, in version 2022.2.2, the menu is renamed to `Help | My Productivity`.

Answer (score 38):

Ctrl Alt T brings a new terminal window in Linux systems. So right approach is
Menu->Code and select Surround with...

Comment: I am using ideavim plugin + intellij on mac. Ctrl/Cmd+alt+T didn't work for me. I had to select the code and then Menu Code ->"surround with"

Comment: Or you can map it to other key stroke like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/40106131/2940265

Comment: On my Ubuntu 16.04 `Ctrl+Super+Alt+T` works by default.

Comment: Ctrl+Super+Alt+T is not working anymore in Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: Super key = windows key.

Answer (score 23):

Ubuntu:

```
"alt+c" -> "s" -> "6"
```

Mac:

```
"cmd+alt+t" -> "6"
```

Win (also Linux distrs if no conflict with system key binding):

```
"ctrl+alt+t" -> "6"
```

Comment: select 6 for Android Studio

Answer (score 19):

**To recap and overview all situations, one might do:**

1. Indicate which portion of code to surround:

   - Keep the pointer on the line you wish to surround or
   - Select the the whole lines you wish to surround (can't surround partial lines)
2. Command:

   - Win: `Ctrl-Alt-T, 6` or `Alt+C, S, 6`
   - Mac: `Command+Alt+T, 6`
   - Linux: `Alt+C, S, 6`

Lastly, don't forget to use the `Productivity Guide` under the `Help menu`.

Comment: Good way to use hot key of Menu! Thanks!

Comment: Your Linux keystroke is a menu browsing. Anyway you can map it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40106131/2940265

Answer (score 18):

If you only need to wrap one line in a try-catch, you can use the [Postfix Completion](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/postfix-completion/#sthash.mI1AHa17.dpuf), available in IDEA 13.1 EAP and above.

The idea is that all you need to do is append `.try` to your line and the completion will be able to wrap it in a try-catch.

For example:

```
System.out.println("Hello World!");.try
```

results in

```
try {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Very nice! but seems doesn't works anywhere, at the end of return statements, for example.

Answer (score 8):

Select the code block to surround and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> (or right-click the selection and select Surround with… from the menu). IntelliJ IDEA will show a list of options to choose from.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Intellij Idea provide **surround with** functionality for that. below link you can see what you can achieve with **surround with**
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/surrounding-blocks-of-code-with-language-constructs.html

If you are using Ubuntu and already read above answers you may see that default key shortcut for **surround with** `Ctrl+Alt+T` is open terminal in Ubuntu.
So one way to use **surround with** is, in Menu **Code -> Surround with**. But this not let us use Intellij core promise of only keyboard development. To keep the promise Intellij let us to use our own keyboard shortcuts.

For That go to 
**File -> Setting -> Keymap**  in there you you can see a search box. Type the functionality you want (Surround with). Right click on Surround with, then select **Remove Ctrl+Alt+T**. Then again right click and select **Add Keyboard Shortcut** The Give keystroke you need (ex: press Ctrl + Alt + P) Then press Ok. It might prompt an error saying the keystroke in use, If you want it press **Leave**. Then press **Apply**

If you want to know default key strokes in Intellij Idea, check this pdf provided by Jetbrains

**[Updated Link]**
https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

Answer (score 3):

For beloved Mac users it's:
Command Alt T

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu users, We can use **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>**

Answer (score -1):

select the code and press alt+shift+z..

Comment: This works when you have your Keymap set to Eclipse in Android Studio's IDE Settings ... for mac it would obviously be command-alt-z

Comment: I think He should mention if there need an extra configuration for that key stroke. Because the default keystroke is `Alt + Ctrl + T` according to this pdf https://resources.jetbrains.com/assets/products/intellij-idea/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf