# Automated "fix" for Java codebase with only generic `catch (Exception e)`

Tags: java, exception, automated-refactoring

I have a large codebase which has many, many instances of the

```
try {
   // attempt to do something important
} catch (Exception e) {
   // do something lame
}
```

antipattern.  Roughly 700 instances.  I'm wondering if there is a tool (e.g., an IDE or something) that could magically, and in mass, replace all of these things with the next tier of specialized catch blocks.  Something that would apply mass-refactoring similar to IntelliJ's or Eclipse's ["wrap with try/catch"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583983/wrap-with-try-catch-in-intellij) in the manner shown below.   NOTE:  I'm not saying all 700 are known `IOException`s; this is just an example assuming the only exception type thrown in the specific case was an `IOException`).

The refactoring I'm seeking is something that does the same semantic analysis of the `try{}` block that IntelliJ/Eclipse does to provide that "wrap with catch" or "add to throws clause" quick-fixes:

```
try {
   // attempt to do something important
   // where an IOException is thrown
} catch (IOException e) {
   // still do something lame
}
```

I understand that this doesn't "fix" the problem, but it saves a step-by-step manual bit of archaeology.

Ideas?

Related question on [detecting general exception catch antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2666057/is-there-a-way-to-make-eclipse-report-a-general-catch-exception-e-as-an-erro).

Comment: Even if it was possible, what would you put in the catch block?

Comment: What would you want in the catch block, and to what aim are you doing this? You would still need a catch Exception block or you are changing the semantics.

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea to change all 700 instances at once? It doesn't seem like this can safely be done mindlessly and without testing. One of the reasons that this is an antipattern is that it suppresses exceptions that you want to know about and deal with; if you eliminate the antipattern everywhere at once, you might suddenly have to deal with more than you expect!

Comment: @ruakh: I'm pretty sure its a bad thing to change all the instances at once, willy nilly.  I'm equally sure that it's bad to leave as-is, because the semantics aren't understood.

Comment: @MiserableVariable: Would transpose the existing catch block contents.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: With not a *single* specialized exception catch block around, you think I'm worried about semantics?  You probably think I have tests in place, too.

Comment: @andersoj: I'm not suggesting leaving it as-is. I'm suggesting changing individual instances individually, and testing to make sure no new problems arise. What happens if some of those `catch` blocks are actually catching huge numbers of `NullPointerException`s? You don't want to change it to let the `NullPointerException` pass through without *also* fixing the underlying problem(s).

Comment: I don't see why sed woudln't work for this.  All you're after is a (dangerous) global search/replace.

Comment: Fair points, all.  It's a bad situation.  Looking to avoid the heavy lifting of figuring what checked exceptions need to be caught.

Comment: Somebody can post a canonical "Don't Do This" answer if they want.  Agree it's a fair point.

Comment: Unless the behaviour is different, this wouldn't make any difference AFAICS

Comment: @jahroy: unless your sed is smarter than mine, it would not be able to determine what checked exceptions are thrown in the `try{}` block

Comment: I think this could be done safely (I don't know of any tools that do it).  Just replace `try { some code that could throw A,B,C} catch ( Exception ) { lame }` with `try { some code that could throw A,B,C } catch ( A, B, C, RuntimeException ) { lame }`  It is not useful except as a first step in code improvement.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: It would not immediately change the behavior.  However, it would be a first step towards actually fixing it, by getting the specialized exception types in place one could then do the heavy lifting of figuring out what should be done.

Comment: I thought we were assuming only IOExceptions were getting thrown. I misunderstood that statement.  Sorry.

Comment: @emory: again, it's not a repeated code pattern that can do search/replace.  It's 700 mostly-different snippets.  All of them do `catch (Exception e) { Log(e); }`  So can't do search/replace w/out some semantic analysis of `try{}` block contents.

Comment: Can you change the behaviour of `Log` instead?  I would only change the exception you actually see in the logs.

Comment: @andersoj - I agree it is not a repeated code pattern, that I why I wrote that I don't know of a tool that will do it.  My point was that you could do this safely, especially if the tool added a RuntimeException at the end.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey:  The intent of the effort is to begin the hard work of analyzing each catch clause and doing something less lame than "Log e".  At least if I can avoid the manual effort of 700 "what checked exceptions are there in the block?" question and move on to the "ok I got an IOException, now what's the right thing to do?" question, which is what I really want to put mental cycles on.

Comment: @emory:  Misread, sorry.

Comment: Do you ever see these exception thrown? What do you actually see logged? I would start with those, you should have the stack trace for them so you can see where they happen.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey:  Yes, they do see these exceptions thrown from time to time.  However, the logging is bad and the thing isn't repeatable.  The ideal approach here is to incrementally get each module under unit test and figure out how to trigger the exceptions... but ideals aren't practical always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the problem is:

Find all blocks of the form:

```
 try { ... }
 catch (Exception e) { ... }
```

with

```
 try { ... }
 catch ( T1 e ) { ... }
 ....
 catch ( Tn e ) { ... }
```

for all T1, ... Tn e,  a program transformation system that can do the code changes, and reason about the exceptions thrown, seems like a solution.

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) with its [Java Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/JavaFrontEnd.html) could likely do this.

You need an analyzer that can compute the set of exceptions thrown from inside the main block.  You likely want to classify those exceptions according to object hierarchy too; if Tm is a specialization of Tn, you may want to generate a handler for Tm and Tn as nested tries.   DMS has full type analysis, so it can determine the types in code, and thrown by a code block. One would have to write custom DMS code to compute the object hierarchy for exceptions.

You need a call graph, so one can propagate the exceptions found up the call graph to the try site.   We have that but it needs some work for Java 1.7.

You need a transformation applier, to revised code.   I think you need to worry about chained catches to handle the general case. With DMS, it should look like:

```
rule specialize_catch(b_try: block,
      E: qualifed_identifer, e: IDENTIFIER, b_recover: block,
      c_pre: catches, c_post: catches):
   statement -> statement
 " try { \b_try } 
   \c_pre
   catch ( \E \e ) { \b_recover }
   \c_post "
 -> 
  " try { \b_try }
    \c_pre 
    catch ( \least_specialized\(\E\,\b_try\,\c_pre\) \e ) { \b_recover }
    catch ( \E e ) { \b_recover }
    \c_post "
    if exists_specialized_exception(E,b_try,c_pre);
```

The syntax to be transformed is code in *meta*quotes "..." to seperate it from the syntax of the rewrite rules.  The rewrite rule has a number of parts.  It specifies a name (we often have hundreds).  It provides a set of named placeholders (b_try, E, b_recover, ...) representing specific, named syntactic forms in the target language (in this case, Java), and written in bare form outside of metaquote and escaped (backslashed) form inside the metaquotes.   c_pre is the name of a series of catch constructs; we can do this because "catches" form an associative list in the abstract, and similarly for the c_post.   It provides for meta-function calls (e.g., least_specialized, exists_specialized_exception) that can can call on custom DMS machinery to compute results (booleans or new syntax [trees]). You'll note the metafunction call to least_specialized even has the syntax for the metafunction call escaped (e.g., the commas and parentheses) since they are not part of the Java language; outside the Java code, such metafunction calls don't need escaping.  And most importantly it has a left hand side ("match this", binding the metavariables) and a right hand side ("replace by this" if the rule condition is true.

The metafunctions least_specialized and exists_specialized would compute, for exceptions that the main code block b_try might throw, and those handled by the existing catches c_pre, and the current exception type E, the most general exception above the c_pre's and below E, and a new catch block is inserted.  If none exist, the if fails and no more exception insertions are made.  You might want additonal transforms to de-clone the duplicated b_recover block.

I obviously haven't implemented this and may not have thought it through completely.   But I can see this as path to a possible solution. YMMV.

I'll say for 700 instances it is probably pretty marginal to do this with DMS. If it took you personally 10 minutes apiece (edit, compile, oops...) that's 7000 minutes or ~~ 100 hours, about 2 weeks.  I doubt you could configure DMS to do this that fast, especially having never done it before.  (I have expert DMS users at my company for which this is likely a workable time frame).

But the claim is that a tool likely does exist.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think any tools exist to do what you are trying. I can think of following algorithm but automating it in a script may take some time...it may even take as much time to write a script as it would take to make the changes manually.

1. Define a new exception

`class NeverThrown extends RuntimeException {}`

1. Global Replace `catch (Exception e)` with `catch (NeverThrown e)`
2. Compile all files
3. For each occurrence of `unreported exception .... must be caught...` identify the exception and add it to the next `catch` block if not already added, e.g. replace `catch (NeverThrown e)` with `catch (NeverThrown, IOException e)`
4. Delete all occurrences of `NeverThrown,` and delete class definition.

Of course, the larger intellectual effort is in determining what to do instead of "something lame". That you will not be able to do in bulk, each case will have to be inspected individually. If I were you, I would stop at step #3 and go through the errors trying to figure out how to handle each uncaught exception reported.

Or you could completely denounce checked exceptions and remove all the try and catch blocks, adding `throws Exception` after each method :)

Comment: Don't you think that some of the magic in Eclipse's factoring engine could be used, maybe with minor hacking, instead of relying upon compiler warnings as in step (3)?

Comment: @andersoj that is the part I am not to sure about. I know refactoring can be saved as a script and reapplied but I don't know if the command saved is `add missing exception to outer try block` or `add IOException to outer try block`.